# Can you recommend a failover solution for setups running multiple VPSes?

Tags: backup, load-balancing, failover, high-availability, redundancy

Here's what I have to work with:

- Root access to VPSes with **different hosting companies** that run CentOS only

  - Two dedicated nameservers with over 100 zone entries
  - Several webservers hosting the same content

The failover solutions I've found either require hardware, clustering in the same network, and other options that I can't access with my VPS setup. And paid DNS failover services are too expensive for the number of domains I have.

It seems implementing DNS failover myself is my best option, though the consensus is that it's not a very good option. Are there **ANY** other solutions I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Linux IP Virtual Server](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org) using tunneling. No need for the "real servers" (webservers) to be on the same subnet.

The ipip encapsulated packages will be ordinary packages that can be firewalled and forwarded.

http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-IPTunneling.html

[keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) is a great tool to handle the service checks and adding/removing failed "real servers"

Answer (score 0):

You can use two dedicated 'entry point' VPS servers running a load balancing software like HAProxy. If there are no geographical constraints, i.e. keeping content close to users or so, you can make all dns/http requests land on the load balancing servers and from there send them to the respective webservers.

There are really cheap services like easyDNS or dyndns where you can delegate DNS availaiblity problem :)